# How to fulfill all the conditions without a repeat?

Tags: java

I have four conditions that must be met together.

```
if (condition 1) { operator 1 };
if (condition 2) { operator 2 };
if ((condition 1) && (condition 2)) { operator 1; operator 2; };
if ((condition 2) && (condition 1)) { operator 2; operator 1; };
```

But in such kind is repeated execution.
How to combine these conditions are to avoid repeating the execution of the operators?

Comment: What's the difference between the 3rd and 4th if statements? Which operator should be called first?

Comment: If you don't want to repeat operators, lines 3 + 4 seem redundant (already covered by 1 + 2).

Comment: You said "four conditions". Are we to assume there are conditions 3 & 4 also?

Comment: I have two buttons that perform these conditions. 
Which condition will be the first depends on which button you press first.

The buttons can be pressed simultaneously.

Comment: So you can have: btn1, btn2, both, or neither? And also btn1 then btn2, and btn2 then btn1

Answer (score 0):

You could use boolean variable, but I don't really see the point to save these two instructions... really... You are using Java to make code more clean!

Answer (score 0):

3 and 4 unnecessary conditions. solution is

```
playOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playOne);
playTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playTwo);
...
public void verification(Button b) {
if (b == playOne) { playSound(sound_one); } 
if (b == playTwo) { playSound(sound_two); }
}
```